# SQL queries via python: in SQL syntax

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pymysql

I'm following [this](http://www.silota.com/docs/recipes/sql-recency-frequency-monetary-rfm-customer-analysis.html) RFM SQL tutorial and running the queries in python with the `pymysql` package.

I keep getting the error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax near '(order by last_order_date) as rfm_recency,
```

I have edited, moved around, copied, pasted the query into a 100 different configurations and can't figure out how to fix it.

My query:

```
query2 = '''

select customer_id, rfm_recency, rfm_frequency, rfm_monetary

from 
    (
        select customer_id,
            ntile(4) over (order by last_order_date) as rfm_recency,
            ntile(4) over (order by count_order) as rfm_frequency,
            ntile(4) over (order by sum_amount) as rfm_monetary


    from 

        (
           select customer_id,
               max(local_date) as last_order_date,
               count(*) as count_order,
               sum(amount) as sum_amount
           from transaction
           group by customer_id) as T

        ) as P
```

And the general python code:

```
con = pymysql.connect(
        host='127.0.0.1', port=server.local_bind_port, db='whatever', user='me',
        password='pass')
    
    
cur = con.cursor()
    
try:
    cur.execute(query2)

 except pymysql.Error as e:
        
        print(" Error is: %d: %s" %(e.args[0], e.args[1]))
```

The error is at the line `ntile(4) over (order by last_order_date) as rfm_recency`

Can anybody here figure out where I'm going wrong?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? MySQL doesn't have window functions until 8.x.'

Comment: Did you read the section "Postgres vs. MySQL" at the site you linked to?

Comment: mysql server version: 5.7.15.... I guess this is the reason for the error. I am a SQL noob though.. can you recommend an alternative to the window functions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31209608/quartiles-in-sql-query