# Avoid double inserted information in database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hey guys I have a table called username, and in my programm i have the possibility to create new users with an username and a password.

But I dont want to have two users with the same username

Im using php and mysql.

How can I handle this?

thx nubu

Comment: Unique key constraint

Comment: [Differences between INDEX, PRIMARY, UNIQUE, FULLTEXT in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/707874/differences-between-index-primary-unique-fulltext-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

add `UNIQUE` constraint so to enforce distinct values on the column,

```
ALTER TABLE tableNAme ADD CONSTRAINT tb_unique UNIQUE(username)
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/395af/1)

Comment: I altered my table and added an unique index ... after that i tried to add a new user with the same username. it didnt work ... o_o :(

Comment: can you post the result of this statement? `DESC yourTableName`?

Comment: sorry i think i wrote it a little bit weird, it works, i can add users into the db BUT also users with the same usernamen eventhough i added this unique index u talke about

Comment: what is that tb_unique?

Comment: it is the name of the `constraint`, you can name whatever you want `:)`

Comment: error ... duplicate entry for my Constraint name (unique_username) ...

Comment: because there are already records in your table. try to remove the duplicates of empty your table first then execute the query.

Comment: im pretty sure that i added this unique property but its still not working ... i saw ur example its pretty easy to understand ... but when it comes to my case it doenst work ... ? o.O

EDIT: Ah k i will try it

Comment: As I've said, there are already records on your table. If you try to empty it first or remove those duplicates, it will surely work.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the name already exists an ask the user to select a different name;

```
SELECT COUNT(username) FROM users WHERE userName = '[name to check]'
```

and add a unique index to the username field

Comment: can i realize it in php and if yes how ... that i check every column and if the username is equals to my post ... its not possible to save this user?