# MySQL - INSERT without duplicating rows (without informing the PK)

Tags: mysql, database, duplicates

I have to insert a few values into a mysql table, but only if there are no other (almost) equal rows, for example:

```
TABLE T
KEY | COL1 | COL2
1   | abc  | 123
2   | def  | 456
```

The KEY column uses auto increment, and I don't inform it on the statement, like this:

```
INSERT INTO T (COL1, COL2) VALUES (abc, 123)
```

The statement above have the same values as the first row. How can I inform mysql that I don't want to insert if the row is a duplicate like that?

I googled for some solutions and found `INSERT IGNORE, ..ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE and REPLACE` in which I would have to inform the PK, but I don't know it (without using a extra query).

Comment: Is this what you looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198397/mysql-how-to-set-the-primary-key-on-phpmyadmin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ON DUPLICATE KEY` and `INSERT IGNORE` will work with any unique index, not just the primary key. So you can add a unique index for these columns:

```
ALTER TABLE T
ADD UNIQUE INDEX (col1, col2);
```

Making it a multi-column index means that the combination has to be unique, even though each column can be duplicated individually.

Comment: yep, thought that, but none of them is actually unique, only the entire combination would be

Comment: That's why it's a multi-column key, that means that the combination has to be unique.

Answer (score 2):

you can do like...

```
>   INSERT INTO memos(id,text) 
>     SELECT 5, 'text to insert' 
>     WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM memos WHERE id = 5 AND text = 'text to insert');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if not exists(select * from t where col1 = "abc" and col2 ="123")then 
  insert into t (col1,col2) values("abc",123 );
end if;
```

Comment: `IF` statements can only be used in procedures, not normal queries.