# Unique Index on a single column vs Adding a Unique Constraint?

Tags: mysql

What is the key difference between Unique Index on a single column and Adding a Unique Constraint ?

I found this [link](http://www.solidq.com/sqj/Pages/2010_November_Issue/Unique-Constraints-vs-Unique-Indexes.aspx), which gives explanation about this on SQL_Server.

I tried to look through mySQL documentation, but could not understand it clearly.

Comment: [Differences between INDEX, PRIMARY, UNIQUE, FULLTEXT in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/707874/differences-between-index-primary-unique-fulltext-in-mysql)

Comment: I believe it's same thing