# If I have a UNIQUE index on a column, do I need to index it again to optimize search queries?

Tags: mysql

I have this table

```
CREATE TABLE `country` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I want to add a unique index so that the table cannot contain duplicate countries.

*Edit:* To clarify, I want the `name` column to have unique values, but I also want to optimize it for queries like `SELECT name FROM country WHERE name = ?`.

If my table were to allow duplicate countries, I'd normally achieve this with an `INDEX` key..

Do I need two indices on the `name` column (one `INDEX` and one `UNIQUE`) or will a single `UNIQUE` index do the job?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Differences between INDEX, PRIMARY, UNIQUE, FULLTEXT in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/707874/differences-between-index-primary-unique-fulltext-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the database to enforce that the column `name` contains UNIQUE values, you'd need a **`UNIQUE KEY`** in place of **`KEY`**.

If you want the database to allow duplicate values for `name`, then the `KEY` you have is just fine.