# SQL - Primary vs Unique not null

Tags: mysql, sql

I've seen some examples of SQL that read like this:

```
email varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL UNIQUE KEY
```

However it seems like it would be more efficient to write it like this:

```
email varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci PRIMARY KEY
```

Is this a fair judgement, or are they actually different?

Comment: Have a look into this SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/707874/differences-between-index-primary-unique-fulltext-in-mysql

Comment: You can have more than one UNIQUE key in a table, while you're restricted to a single PRIMARY key. Not all databases can add foreign keys to UNIQUE constrained fields.

Comment: an email address shouldn't be used as a primary key... it can definitely be required to be unique, though.