# laravel do I need index() on unique() column?

Tags: php, laravel

When I put unique() on column in laravel migration, I don't need to put index() anymore right? Unique already creates an index for fast search?

Comment: Yes `unique()` alone is enough. Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/707874/1903366) for a comparison between the different indexes

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes `unique()` alone is enough. It will create a `UNIQUE` index on the table which basically is the same as a "normal" `INDEX` but also enforces the constraint that there can be no two rows with the same value.

So in terms of performance `UNIQUE` should be at least the same if not even faster. No need to add an additional index.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/707874/1903366) has a nice answer comparing the different indexes of MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

No , You do not need to put index() anymore.

Comment: No it isn't but when you say it like that (even though you are right) it sounds more like an opinion than a well-founded answer.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for your nice comment , I have up-votted you . Cheers !

Comment: No worries... and thanks. Also keep in mind, that these answers aren't just for the OP but are supposed to help other people having the same or a similar struggle in the future :)

Comment: what was wrong with his answer?