# Fetch data on onKeyUp event using Fulltext (even when entering signle character in my search)

Tags: php, sql, ajax, html, mysqli

I used `fulltext` index in a column in my table.

Here is simple html.

```
<form>
<input type="text" name='search' placeholder="Enter your search" id="input" onKeyUp="update()" onChange="update()"  autocomplete="off" >
<input type="text" style="display: none">
<input type="button" name="tp" id="tr" value="search" >
</form>
```

I searched in database using ajax. When i just typed a character it fire off the function update() because of `onKeyUp` event in search input. But it doesn't fetch any data from the database until I typed a fulltext (meaning like 'hemant' ).
I want to fetch the data when i just type (even a single character), I don't want to use `LIKE` keyword to use because it doesn't allow me to search in two or more column and also it doesn't give me nearby words option.

> $sql = "SELECT * FROM data WHERE MATCH (name, email) AGAINST
>   ('$search') ";

I also want to know that by using fulltext index. Does it search fast?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Differences between INDEX, PRIMARY, UNIQUE, FULLTEXT in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/707874/differences-between-index-primary-unique-fulltext-in-mysql)

Comment: Do not confuse the term `FULLTEXT` with searching on a whole word vs string fragment.  Is has nothing to do with that.  In this context it describes the type of index used for the column, i.e. specific to `MATCH() / AGAINST() `.  Sounds like you just need to use two `LIKE` statements in your criteria, typical auto complete scenario....