# Mysql Select query speed up

Tags: mysql, select

i am using to fetch record from database and records are likely be '590096' and query table time around 4 sec and i want to make it more faster which is like

less then 1 sec can you please guide me how should i do this i am using normal select query

```
SELECT count(*) from table where field6 > '$s'
```

i am also using date like below given code for condition

```
$t15m_ago = new DateTime("15 minutes ago");
$s = $t15m_ago->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

would it be due to this?

Below is my database

```
CREATE TABLE table (
  field0 int NOT NULL auto_increment,
  field1 varchar(20),
  field2 int,
  field3 int,
  field4 varchar(255),
  field5 varchar(60),
  field6 DATETIME,
  PRIMARY KEY(field0)
)
```

What exactly i want to do with select query i count records from table will last 15 mins. my table is inserting thousands of records in every sec.

Comment: Show CREATE TABLE and EXPLAIN SELECT

Comment: You should take a look at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select-optimization.html One thing you could try is using an index in your select instead of *

Answer (score 0):

You could create an index on `field6`. It will speed up queries with `field6` in condition.

```
CREATE INDEX field6_idx ON table(field6);
```

Comment: here idx is already primary key which is unique so do we still need to create index inspite of that too?

Comment: Of course. You can have more indexes in one table. They have more functions than just uniqueness. Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/708508/4724920) for more about different kinds of indexes.

Answer (score 0):

To speed up the query you can do following things

```
- SELECT count(field0) from table where field6 > '$s' rather than using *
- Apply indexes to the column
- Add limit 1 as count(field0) will itself return 1 row
```

please let me know if you still need more information.

Thanks
Amit

Comment: amit if adding limit 1 as count() will itself return 1 row then what is the use of that? here i do not know how much data it will be wether 1 2 or 100 or 1000 so their is no use to use limit here

Comment: @AnilDhiman Using `LIMIT 1` in a `COUNT` query makes no difference result wise. It will still count all the matching rows, but return only 1 row as a result (the number of matching rows), just like your original query. Whether using it actually affects performance, I couldn't say.

Comment: @AnilDhiman we do have information_schema database exists for mysql server, which keeps track of meta information, like auto increment, total rows, last modified time of table etc. so when we use count() it will not actually calculate all rows from table, and it will get the counts from information schema database and related tables.