# How do I prevent multiple entries like this in database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Is there anyway to prevent a user from clicking like multiple times without having them be inserted into the database like this?

[image]

I know I could just disable the button, but I want do this all without reloading the page.

```
    $dbh = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "testdb");
$postid = $_POST['postid'];
if(isset($_POST['liked'])&& empty($_SESSION[$postid])){
    $_SESSION[$postid] = TRUE;

    $userid = $_SESSION['username'];
    $result = mysqli_query($dbh,"SELECT * FROM user_images WHERE id=$postid");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $n = $row['likes'];
    mysqli_query($dbh,"INSERT INTO likes(username, postid) VALUES('$userid', '$postid')");
    mysqli_query($dbh,"UPDATE user_images SET likes=$n+1 WHERE id=$postid");
    echo $n+1;
    exit();
}


if (isset($_POST['unliked'])){
    $postid = $_POST['postid'];
    $result = mysqli_query($dbh,"SELECT * FROM user_images WHERE id=$postid");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $n = $row['likes'];
    $userid = $_SESSION['username'];
    //delete from likes before updating
    mysqli_query($dbh,"DELETE FROM likes WHERE postid=$postid AND username=$userid");
    mysqli_query($dbh,"UPDATE user_images SET likes=$n-1 WHERE id=$postid");
    echo $n-1;
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Just check what's in the database before you insert something new.

Comment: As noted previously, pleasssse don't use this code. You are open to SQL injections, and doing more than you need to.

Comment: You can make a primary key from username & postid and on the second insert it will give you an error.

Comment: What if I have multiple users that have multiple posts? ...I tried using UNIQUE INDEX, both no luck there.

Comment: As to your current issue, you could create a session and once they vote set the specific session value to true, if they come again and already set disallow.

Comment: I'm getting this error: `Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key` @Radu

Comment: Unique INDEX on both keys combined together should not allow 2 lines with same username and postid in likes table

Comment: @chris85 How would I write that into my code? Sorry, I'm still learning PHP and SQL.

Comment: `session_start()` at the start. Move `$postid = $_POST['postid'];` to outside the conditionals. Add `&& empty($_SESSION[$postid])` inside the conditional statement. Have `$_SESSION[$postid] = TRUE;` in the conditional blocks after the confirming the `insert`/`update` worked.

Comment: I was able to confirm that the information went in the database, but I can still insert it multiple times @chris85

Comment: Can you update the question with your new code.

Comment: I updated it @chris85

Comment: Please note that your server is open to SQL injection attacks.  This Q&A will tell you how to do database interactions safely: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: You need it on `unlike` as well... and you have `session_start()` as well?

Comment: Yes the session_start is at the very top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to create a [unique index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707874/differences-between-index-primary-unique-fulltext-in-mysql) in the table, to ensure that no duplicates entries are allowed even if you have a mistake in your PHP code. Since an user can like several posts you have to make the index using both columns:

```sql
create unique index IDU_likes on likes (username,postid);
```

Then you have to modify your code and check if the insert failed (you should be doing it *always* anyway). Also, the code you are using is open to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), you should use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) and [bind the variables](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) instead of manually constructing the query, for example:

```php
$stmt=mysqli_prepare($dbh,"INSERT INTO likes(username, postid) VALUES(?, ?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,'si',$userid,$postid);
if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt) {
  $n=$n+1;
  $stmt=mysqli_prepare($dbh,"UPDATE user_images SET likes=? WHERE id=?");
  mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,'ii',$n,$postid);
  mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)
}
echo $n;
```

Comment: Thank you so much... but why can't a delete a user from the `likes` table?

Comment: What do you mean, that you get an error when you try to delete an user? What error are you getting? (use [`mysqli_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) for getting the last DB error).

Comment: @AlbertoMarinez I'm Sorry!! It was because of my quotations. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
        if(isset($_POST['liked'])){
    $postid = $_POST['postid'];
    $userid = $_SESSION['username'];
    $result = mysqli_query($dbh,"SELECT * FROM user_images WHERE id=$postid");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $n = $row['likes'];
    $check_query = mysqli_query($dbh,"SELECT * FROM likes WHERE username = '$userid' AND postid = '$postid'");
    $found = mysqli_num_rows($check_query);
    if ($found == 0) {
       mysqli_query($dbh,"INSERT INTO likes(username, postid) VALUES('$userid', '$postid')");
       mysqli_query($dbh,"UPDATE user_images SET likes=$n+1 WHERE id=$postid");
       echo $n+1;
   }
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, can you take a look at my `isset($_POST['unliked']`? I can't delete anything for some reason...

Comment: well, it doesn't really tell me, but when I go to the database once I click the 'unlike' button, it doesn't delete