# how to index string column in laravel?

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have table `customer_Settings` which has column `key` ,value,id,customer_id

```
$table->integer('id);
$table->integer('customer_id');
$table->string('key');
$table->string('value`);
```

Here is my query which i am using to get data

```
$customer_setting = CustomerSetting::select('customer_id','key','value')->where('customer_id', $customer_id)->where("key", $key)->get();
```

My question is which type of indexing we should do on `customer_settings` table. full_text?

if yes we want to use `whereIn` on key column . I mean to say i will give an `array` of keys query needs to get data according to that

Any suggestions please

Comment: You can use `whereIn` without the `key` column being indexed. Also indexing is done on a single column, not a table. I'm unsure why indexing is being asked about in this context.

Comment: i know i can use whereIn without indexing but i want to index key column. i want to know which type of indexing i should use on string type column. BTREE or FULLTEXT

Comment: If it is a key like `Ak2DtepDbVC` and `BcD2ldpWBNk`, I would recommend `BTREE`, look about the differences on youtube.

Comment: BTREE and FULLTEXT are very different. FULLTEXT is actually much more than just an index. If you need to search for text WITHIN the value of a column, you will need to use FULLTEXT, otherwise BTREE would be fine.

Comment: This should help you decide. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707874/differences-between-index-primary-unique-fulltext-in-mysql